# Creating scope for last change values in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on an app which based on API e.g. every night update my database based on the API main database.

There is a column `LastChangeTimestamp` I'm creating a scope for `price_change_time` e.g. below

```
scope :price_change_time, -> {where("LastChangeTimestamp BETWEEN ? AND ?", (Time.zone.now - 1.day).beginning_of_day, (Time.zone.now - 1.day).end_of_day)}
```

but this is not working and error below.

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "lastchangetimestamp" does not exist

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: what you really want to achieve by comparing two identical dates .

Comment: Just need change time is last one day

Comment: This will still not give you current day's changes

Comment: Make sure you create records between that time to test if it's working or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to the following added single quotes on the column like `'LastChangeTimestamp'` then query will look like

```
scope :price_change_time, -> {where("'LastChangeTimestamp' BETWEEN ? AND ?", (Time.zone.now - 1.day).beginning_of_day, (Time.zone.now - 1.day).end_of_day)}
```

Rails by default searching `lastchangetimestamp` on the table but your column name is `LastChangeTimestamp` that's why he didn't recognize `LastChangeTimestamp` column

Or you can rename your column like `lastchangetimestamp` or `last_change_timestamp` and query scope update based on this.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use rails query [**`range operator '..'`**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Range.html)

```
scope :price_change_time, -> {where(LastChangeTimestamp: (Time.zone.now - 1.day).beginning_of_day..(Time.zone.now - 1.day).end_of_day)}
```

Comment: On the question he said column name is `LastChangeTimestamp` and he wrote query using this but pg showing he didn't find `lastchangetimestamp` that means somehow rails didn't send with uppercase column name that's why need to use single quote to send this name exact, you can suggest him to change column name

Comment: yes exactly thats why i suggested him to check `schema.rb`, you can add your suggestion to my answer thanks for pointing this out